# How can I prevent amChart line chart from auto grouping data?

Tags: typescript, angular8, amcharts

I'm working with amChart 4 on Angular 8.0.1.  The problem is that it auto groups data and give a vertical line representing the range of that day, instead of drawing out each point and show the trends.  The latter is what I expect.

What I get:
[image]

What I expected:
[image]

I've commented all additional settings and keep only the essential codes:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    this.chart = am4core.create(this.chartElement.nativeElement, XYChart);
    const dateAxis = this.chart.xAxes.push(new DateAxis());
    const valueAxis = this.chart.yAxes.push(new ValueAxis());
    const series = this.chart.series.push(new LineSeries());
    series.dataFields.dateX = this.dateField; // dateField = 'DATE_TIME'
    series.dataFields.valueY = this.valueField; // valueField = 'ALL'
    
    if (this.pending && this.pending.length) {
      this.chart.data = pending;
      this.pending = [];
    }
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.data$.subscribe(data => {
    if (this.chart) {
      this.chart.data = data;
    } else {
      this.pending = data;
    }
  });
}
```

While my data is an array with about 15K points, format as below:

```js
[
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2020-03-13T07:04:34.410Z",
    "ALL": 4335
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2020-03-13T07:05:46.900Z",
    "ALL": 4332
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2020-03-13T07:06:58.720Z",
    "ALL": 4344
  },
  // ...
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2020-03-25T17:53:08.720Z",
    "ALL": 5606.59
  },
  {
    "DATE_TIME": "2020-03-25T17:54:20.870Z",
    "ALL": 5575.9400000000005
  }
]
```

What I guess is that, the data is too large so amCharts automatically group data by date.
But is there anyway that I can cancel this default setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For date-based charts, AmCharts assumes daily data (`yyyy-MM-dd`), which explains why your chart looks that way. Since your data has an accompanying timestamp (ISO8601), you need to modify the [`inputDateFormat`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Parsing_dates_in_data) to tell the chart to also parse out the time component. AmCharts provides a special `i` format code to automatically parse ISO dates:

```
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = 'i';
```

You can find more format codes [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-date-time/)

You'll also want to specify a [`baseInterval`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Manually_specifying_data_granularity) on your date axis to match the granularity of your date data so the chart can draw the series and axis correctly.

```
dateAxis.baseInterval = {
  timeUnit: "minute",
  count: 1
};
```